# iterate through csv character-by-character

Tags: python, csv

I am currently doing an exercise building a python CSV parser. I need to be able to open a CSV file and read the contents, iterating through the CSV character-by-character. My python code is set up to iterate through strings however I've run into a errors doing this through the CSV.

Read method:

```
import csv
def parse(csv):
    #states
    is_token = False
    previous_character_is_escape = False
    no_quote_value = False

    csv_file = open(csv, 'r')
    iterator = (csv.reader(csv_file))

    for i in iterator:
        if is_token == False:
            if i == '"':
                print '\b' + i,
                is_token = True
                no_quote_value = False
            elif i == ',':
                print '\n',
            elif no_quote_value == True:
                print '\b' + i,
                is_token = True
            else:
                print '\b' + i,


        elif is_token == True:
            if i == '\\':
                print '\b' + i,
                previous_character_is_escape = True
            elif previous_character_is_escape == True and i == '"':
                print '\b' + i,
                previous_character_is_escape = False
            elif previous_character_is_escape == False and i == '"':
                print '\b' + i,
                is_token = False
                no_quote_value = True
            elif no_quote_value == True and i == ',':
                print '\n',
                is_token = False
            elif no_quote_value == False and i == ',':
                print '\b' + i,
            else:
                print '\b' + i,

parse('example.csv')
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_test.py", line 47, in <module>
    parse('example.csv')
  File "main_test.py", line 10, in parse
    iterator = (csv.reader(csv_file))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

Is there any way to open a CSV file and read the content character by character?

Comment: hmm, can't you just open it as a regular text file?? if you wanna read character by character, you should not care about the csv module

Comment: Your variable called `csv` is conflicting with the module name `csv`. Change it to something different.

Comment: That's the reason for the error, but as @cedbeu says, you shouldn't be using `csv` if you want to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file being basically a text file, I would say you should read it as a regular text file... In other words, if you want to build your own parser, you should not be using an existing parser...

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for l in f:
        for c in l:
            pass # your c-by-c processing here
```

**Note** that the regular column separator in "comma separated values" (CSV) format is a comma... But, sometimes (most of the time actually), it's a tab, a semi-colon, or some other chars... Take care about this while parsing... Regarding rows, "end-of-line character" (EOL) depends on the encoding of your file (standard on *nix is `\n`, on Mac is `\r`, on Windows is  `\r\n`)

Comment: Thanks @cedbue This worked for me! Appreciate your input. It was silly of me to try to use the csv module when I was constructing my own parser!

Answer (score 0):

That might because you name you parameter `csv`, which confuse the computer with the csv module, change another name and try it again.